# How Can I call correctly addAttribute method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, methods

I have made a method what I call addAttribute with 2 arguments what are strings.I want to create a new element with this method.I want to use this method to add attributes to the new class.
I have created another method with other arguments.

```
public addAttribute(key: string, value: string): void {
    this.AdditionalAttributes.set(key, value);
};
```

```
const tag2 = new ClassName(

    this.addAttribute("Type", "Test"),

    this.addAttribute("V", "1"),

    this.addAttribute("U", "1"),

);
```

I got this error log:
    TypeError: this.addAttribute is not a function

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that `addAttribute` is a method of `ClassName`. In that case, the correct way of writing things will be to create an instance first, and then call it. For example:

```
const tag2 = new ClassName();
tag2.addAttribute("Type", "Test");
tag2.addAttribute("V", "1");
tag2.addAttribute("U", "1");
```

I'm not sure what's the definition of the constructor of your `ClassName`, but since `addAttribute` returns `void`, you cannot possibly use the result as parameters to construct `ClassName`.

Comment: This is how my class looks like without addAttribute method:

protected Type: string;
  protected V: number;
  protected U: string;
  protected Title: string;
  protected WF: number;
  
  public AdditionalAttributes: Map<string, string>= new Map<string, string>();

  constructor(Type: string, V: number, U: string, Title: string, WF: number) {
    this.Type = Type;
    this.V = V;
    this.U = U;
    this.Title = Title;
    this.WF = WF;
    this.AdditionalAttributes = this.AdditionalAttributes;
  }

Comment: @koko91kon In that case you don't need to call `addAttribute` method, you just write `const tag2 = new ClassName("Test", 1, "1", [some title string], [whatever number WF is supposed to be]);`.